# JPA Criteria Query GROUP and COUNT over subquery

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jpa-criteria

Given the following SQL structure of `MY_TABLE`:

```
GROUP_LABEL | FILE  | TOPIC
-----------------------------
group A     | 1.pdf | topic A
group A     | 1.pdf | topic B
group A     | 2.pdf | topic A
group B     | 2.pdf | topic B
```

My task is to get this stuff grouped by `GROUP_LABEL`, while forgetting about the different `TOPIC`s of a file. So my expected result is

```
GROUP_LABEL | COUNT(*) 
----------------------
group A     | 2       -- two different files 1.pdf and 2.pdf here
group B     | 1       -- only one file here
```

In pure SQL I would do it like

```
SELECT GROUP_LABEL, COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_LABEL, FILE FROM MY_TABLE
);
```

Is it possible to transform it into a JPA Criteria API query? I don't have any idea to get my inner query into the from construct of the Criteria query, in 9.3.1 of https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html it seems like this is not possible.

But I just can't believe it ;-) Has anyone done this before? The inner query would be enriched with various, well-tested, filter Predicates which I would want to reuse.

I'm using `spring-boot-starter-data : 1.5.6.RELEASE` with mainly standard configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Firstly** your sql query can be resumed to this :

```
Select distinct GLOBAL_LABEL ,count (distinct FILE) from MY_TABLE group by GLOBAL_LABEL
```

**Secondly** it's always good to not name your columns with primary names to avoid problems.

**Finaly** you can use this as your HQL query (with no magic) :

```
Select distinct ge.globalLabel,count (distinct ge.file) from GlobalEntity ge group by ge.globalLabel
```

Comment: This looks good, I've succesfully converted it to Criteria API with CriteriaBuilder. The `count(distinct FILE)` did the job. If you update your answer with a snippet for the CriteriaBuilder, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Query: `select label, count(distinct file) from tableName group by label;`

Criteria: `criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.groupProperty("label")).add(Projections.countDistinct("file")));`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible by using [JPA javax.persistence.criteria API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/package-summary.html).

[Take a look at this example in the official Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria-group-by).